# How to convert date field in single line of text using Calculated columns

Tags: calculated-column, date-time

I have created a calculated field for a content type in my Sharepoint 2010 and I want to return a date in the TEXT format because I am returning some text with it. The condition I have put in the formula is:

```
IF(
    AND([ShowModifiedDate];[ShowCreatedDate]);
    "Create date is [Created] and update date is [Modified]";
    IF(
        [ShowModifiedDate];
        [Modified];
        IF(
            [ShowCreatedDate];
            [Created];
            [ArticleDate]
            )
        )
    )
```

Here I have to return the result in "Single Line of Text" instead of "Date time". I have tried TEXT function (`TEXT([Modified],"dd-mm-yyyy")`) for the same but it's always giving an error "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.". But I can't see any error in the query which I am returning. I have all the columns present in the list.

Even though if I write below thing in formula it's returning me the same error..

```
TEXT([Modified],"dd mmm yyyy hh:mm ")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Did you put the "=" in front of the formula in the calculated field?

See pictures below, it worked for me

[image: formular]
[image: display]

Answer (score 2):

If as DateTime its working fine then you can also use the following to get the text

```
DAY(Modified)&"-"&MONTH(Modified)&"-"&YEAR(Modified)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're mixing semicolon separators `;` (in your main formula) and comma separators `,` (in the `TEXT` function).

It's also worth double-checking all your field names are correct: It may be a translation difference, but the `[Changed]` and `[Change]` fields are usually called `[Modified]`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the , and ; issue. But the machine is setup for the DK environment where I have to provide ; instead of , . And the field name there is Changed. Sorry for typo error above. :(. The exact field name is "Oprettet" in DK. Here I have translated the field name. Any other help is highly appreciated. IF I am using the filed with DateTime in formula then it's returning me the correct result. So it means the field is also doing good.

Comment: So you've changed the `,` inside the `TEXT` call to a `;` you're saying? It might help to post the entire broken formula, to clarify the problem.

Comment: here is the formula which I am using into formula field. `IF(AND([Visskabedato];[Visopdateringsdato]);"Create date is [Oprettet] and update date is [Ændret]";IF([Visskabedato];[Oprettet];IF([Visopdateringsdato];[Ændret];[Artikeldato])))`. But now I have done this thing in another way. I have used this article (http://corypeters.net/2008/06/hiding-empty-publishing-fields-in-a-page-layout/) to hide and show the publishing control.